# A version of the first mean value theorem for integrals, proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am asked to prove a version of the first mean value theorem for integrals:

Let $f$ and $g$ be defined on $[a,b]$ with $g$ continuous, $f\ge 0$, and $f$ integrable. Then there is a point $x_0 \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx = g(x_0) \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.
$$

My (incomplete) proof goes as follows:

Since $ [a,b] $ is compact and $ g $ is continuous, we know there exist $ x_1, x_2 \in [a,b] $ such that $ g(x_1) \le g(x) \le g(x_2) $ for any $ x \in [a,b] $. Thus, we have the following string of inequalities
$$
f(x)g(x_1) \le f(x)g(x) \le f(x)g(x_2), \, \, \forall x \in [a,b],
$$
$$
\Rightarrow g(x_1)\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx \,\le \, \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx \, \le  \, g(x_2)\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.
$$

My problem now is to show the final equality. It seems to me the intermediate value theorem is somehow involved, but I cannot see how to use it. Furthermore, how do I make use of the $f\ge 0$ condition in the hypothesis?

Comment: What if $g(x_1) > g(x_2)$ ?

Answer (score 8):

You're almost there.

Let $\displaystyle h(x) = g(x) \int_a^b f(t) \ dt$. As $g$ is continuous, $h$ is also continuous. Without loss of generality, let $x_1 < x_2$.

By what you've shown above, $\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \ dx$ is a number between $h(x_1)$ and $h(x_2)$. As $h$ is continuous, by the IVP there must be a value $x_0 \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that

$$h(x_0) = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \ dx$$

That is, there is an $x_0 \in (x_1, x_2) \subset (a,b) \ $ such that

$$ g(x_0) \int_a^b f(x) \ dx = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \ dx$$

Comment: In your definition of $h(x)$, you write that the integral is in terms of $t$. Why is this necessary? Furthermore, are you treating $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ as a number in this definition, so that $h(x)$ is continuous?

Comment: I used $t$ as the dummy variable of integration in the definition of $h$ to make it clear that it is not at all dependent on $x$. In other words, $\int_a^b f(t) \  dt = \int_a^b f(x)  \ dx$ is just a real number which scales $g(x)$. Make sense?