# Show that there is $c \in [a,b]$ such that $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f(x)g(x) dx = g(c) \int_{a}^b f(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Question:**

> Assume $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and $g$ is integrable and nonnegative over $[a,b]$. Show that there is $c \in [a,b]$ such that $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f(x)g(x) dx = g(c) \int_{a}^b f(x) dx$.

Don't we also need the fact that $f$ is integrable? I would solve this by using integration by parts. That is $$ \int_{a}^b f(x)g(x) dx = f(x) \int g(x) dx -\int_{a}^b \left(\int g(x)dx\right) f'(x) dx$$
 How do we then factor out a $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b f(x) dx$?

Comment: Continuity of $f$ implies integrability.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ then it is integrable.

Comment: $f$ is continuous and  bounded!

Comment: Why must $g(x)$ be integrable?

Comment: It is [Mean Value Theorem for integrals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036829/second-mean-value-theorem-proof)

Comment: False, counterexample, $f(x) = \sin x$, $g(x) = 2+\sin x$ and $[a,b] = [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: I think you have your condition on $f,g$ backwards. $g$ needs to be continuous and $f$ needs to be nonnegative.

Comment: Is there a reason why $f(x)$ is integrable?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is from Wikipedia:

Suppose $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g$ is a nonnegative integrable function on $[a, b]$. By the extreme value theorem, there exists $m$ and $M$ such that for each $x$ in $[a, b]$, $m\leqslant  f(x) \leqslant  M$  and $f[a,b] = [m, M]$. Since $g$ is nonnegative,

$$m \int_a^b g(x) \, dx \leqslant  \int^b_a f(x)g(x) \, dx \leqslant  M \int_a^b g(x) \, dx.$$
Now let

$$I = \int_a^b g(x) \, dx.$$
If $I = 0$, we're done since

$$0 \leqslant  \int_a^b f(x) g(x)\, dx \leqslant  0$$
means

$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\, dx=0,$$
so for any $c$ in $(a, b)$,

$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\, dx = f(c) I = 0.$$
If $I \neq 0$, then

$$m \leqslant  \frac1I \int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx \leqslant  M.$$
By the intermediate value theorem, $f$ attains every value of the interval $[m, M]$, so for some $c$ in $[a, b]$

$$f(c) = \frac1I\int^b_a f(x) g(x) \, dx,$$
that is,

$$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx = f(c) \int_a^b  g(x) \, dx.$$
Finally, if $g$ is negative on $[a, b]$, then

$$M \int_a^b g(x) \, dx \leqslant  \int^b_a f(x)g(x) \, dx \leqslant  m \int_a^b g(x) \, dx,$$
and we still get the same result as above.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $f \geq 0$ and *integrable*, with $g$ *continuous* on $[a,b]$ this should be the Mean Value Theorem for integrals.

Consider the function $$h(x) = g(x)\int_a^b f(t)dt$$ and apply the Intermediate Value Theorem on $h$ by showing that there are $x_1, x_2$ such that $$h(x_1)< g(x)\int_a^b f(t)dt < h(x_2)$$

use the fact that $g$ is continuous on a compact then it has a maximum and minimum.

The way it is sated you may use Achille Hui's as a counterexample.