# Let $f$ Riemann Integrable in $ \left[a,b\right]\ $ Prove exist a $x$ $\in$ $ \left[a,b\right]\ $ such that $ \int_{a}^{x}f=\int_{x}^{b}f $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ Riemann Integrable in $[a,b]\ $ Prove exist a $x\in[a,b]$ such that $ \int_{a}^{x}f=\int_{x}^{b}f $

I tried this:

I need prove this: $ \int_{a}^{x}f-\int_{x}^{b}f=0\Rightarrow\int_{a}^{x}f+\int_{b}^{x}f=0$.

Let $a<x<b$. Then, $ \int_{a}^{b}f=\int_{a}^{x}f+\int_{x}^{b}f.$

In this step I'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: Look at $g(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt-\int_x^bf(t)dt$ and use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You say, this theorem, no? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036829/second-mean-value-theorem-proof @MichaelBurr

Comment: But, i think you say this theorem, Intermediate value theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem, only need $g$ be continuous. But $g$ is continuous because $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ and $G(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt-\int_x^bf(t)dt$ then, for other theorem, $G(x)$ is continuous! @MichaelBurr

Comment: Notice that $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is continuous (it is differentiable, see fundamental theorem of calculus).  Moreover, $\int_x^bf(t)dt$ is also continuous for the same reason.

Comment: Yes! @MichaelBurr, Thanks Michael :D and the last question, when you say  intermediate value theorem, you say this theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem, no?

Comment: Yes, although all you need is the Bolzano theorem (a special case).